# Recursion through 2D Array

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to recursively navigate through a 2d array jumping to a row with the index of a column in which I can find a value. Consider the following 2d array:

```
                             # 0  1  2  3 
    sample_array_of_arrays = [[0, 1, 1, 0], #row 0
                              [0, 0, 1, 1], #row 1
                              [0, 0, 0, 0], #row 2
                              [0, 0, 0, 0]] #row 3
```

This means for the above example: There is a value in row0 at position 1. So I go to row1. I find a value at position 2 so I go to row 2. I dont find any values in row 2 so I terminate. I do this for all possible combinations and end up with following:

```
row0 -> row1 -> row2
row0 -> row1 -> row3
row0 -> row2
```

I have tried a variety of different recursive approaches, but I cant figure it out. This works for one combination (row0 -> row1 -> row2)

```
def rec_go_through_grpah(row,index):

    if sum(sample_array_of_arrays[row])==0:
        print("row " +str(row) + "    reached dead end")
        return
    else:
        while index <= len(sample_array_of_arrays[row]):
            current_element = sample_array_of_arrays[row][index]
            if current_element==0:
                rec_go_through_grpah(row, index+1)
            else:
                print ("row "+str(row) + "->")
                rec_go_through_grpah(index,0)

if __name__=="__main__":

    sample_array_of_arrays = [[0, 1, 1, 0],  # row 0
                              [0, 0, 1, 1],  # row 1
                              [0, 0, 0, 0],  # row 2
                              [0, 0, 0, 0]]  # row 3


    rec_go_through_grpah(0,0)
```

It is an infinite loop and the output is

```
row 0->
row 1->
row 2    reached dead end
row 1->
row 2    reached dead end
row 1->
row 2    reached dead end
row 1->
row 2    reached dead end
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest such solution. You can customize it to get desired output.

```
sample_array_of_arrays = [[0, 1, 1, 0], #row 0
                          [0, 0, 1, 1], #row 1
                          [0, 0, 0, 0], #row 2
                          [0, 0, 0, 0]] #row 3

def dfs(l, row, s):
    s += f"row {row}"
    if not any(l[row]):
        print(s)
        return

    for col, val in enumerate(l[row]):
        if val:
            dfs(l, col, s + " -> " )

dfs(sample_array_of_arrays, 0, '')
```

`dfs` is [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

**Output**

```
row 0 -> row 1 -> row 2
row 0 -> row 1 -> row 3
row 0 -> row 2
```

`dfs` function can be changed to avoid additional list checking by `any` function. May be this will increase performance.

```
def dfs(l, row, s):
    s += f"row {row}"
    flag = False

    for col, val in enumerate(l[row]):
        if val:
            flag = True
            dfs(l, col, s + " -> " )

    if not flag:
        print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The while loop statement should be:

   ```
   while index < len(sample_array_of_arrays[row]):
   ```
2. The main issue: you never increment `index`:

   ```
   while index < len(sample_array_of_arrays[row]):
       if ...:
           ....
       else:
           ....
       index += 1
   ```
3. Another base case is required:

   ```
   if sum(sample_array_of_arrays[row])==0:
       print("row " +str(row) + "    reached dead end")
       return
   else if index >= len(sample_array_of_arrays[row]):
       print("row " +str(row) + "    reached dead end")
       return
   else:
       ....
   ```